# Mercurial replacing values in a file that been cloned?

Tags: mercurial, version-control, tortoisehg

Say I'm cloning a repository that I always clone to `C:\working_copies\<customer-name>\<customer-project>\` and that the project has variables in it's `build.properties` that get filled in with `<customer-name> <customer-project>` (by me) everytime I clone the repo.

Is there a way that I can fill in these values in the file automatically by placing some special value in the file (in ant it's something like `${base-dir}` or something like that) that would fill in these build.property values for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

option 1: make sure build process only relies on relative paths, and dont change name/project variable

option2: write a [hook](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#hooks), specifically a post-clone hook, try the [book](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html) for a hook tutorial

Answer (score 1):

No, Mercurial is completely unaware of what is outside of it's repository folder.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to rig this up using the [Keyword Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/KeywordExtension).  Just set up a HGRC that populates the working directory with the values you want upon update.

Comment: Is there any way to place a regular expression selection taken from the path of the directory?

Comment: You could do so when building the .hgrc file that will include details ont he substitution to make, but you can't have regexp captures evaluated live during keyword replacement that I know of.